# Formulario de compra MercadoPago PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una página, la cuál te muestra 2 artículos para comprar, mi idea es está: al apretar en uno de ellos te redirecciona a un formulario el cual te pide tu nombre, apellido, correo (al que se te enviará luego un mensaje con el pago efectuado) y localidad.

Luego de completar el formulario te redirecciona a la página de MercadoPago, una vez realizado el pago correctamente tendría que redireccionarte a una página en la cual aparezca el texto "pago realizado correctamente" y sin que vea el usuario tendría que almacenar los datos ingresados anteriormente en el formulario (nombre, apellido, etc.) En mi base de datos MySQL.

Esa es la idea que tengo sobre cómo hacerlo, no sé si es correcto o es lo más adecuado, pero al momento de que se efectúe el pago necesito tener los datos de la persona que me compro. Si esa idea es correcta mi duda es: cuando el usuario completa el formulario y le da al botón de pagar, antes de ser redireccionado a MercadoPago, almaceno esos datos en mi base de datos, el usuario es llevado a MercadoPago, realiza el pago, y cuando es redireccionado a la página con el texto "pago realizado correctamente" como hago para vincular los datos del formulario que se encuentran en mi BD con el pago que se realizó recién.?

Comment: Lo que dices es correcto, pero no debes de guardar los datos si el pago no ha sido realizado ya que yambien puede ser pendiente o fallido o cancelado, debes de guardar los datos en una variable de sesión y con ayuda de las **Back_url** guardar los datos dependiendo del estado de la compra

Comment: Se puede guardar datos temporalmente sin hacer uso de MySql? No lo sabía, investigare sobre `Back_url` @christian

Comment: Si, utiliza las sesiones, es como las cokies pero estas no se pueden cambiar ni eliminar, al menos que se cierre el navegador